# Hotel Room Booking problem Query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing a problem with hotel room booking on a different date for the same room.
Suppose,

```
id----room_id------checkindate---------checkoudate
1-----1001--------12-10-2020-----------15-10-2020
2-----1001--------16-10-2020-----------30-10-2020
```

Room Booking

```
            $room=Room::find($id);
            // $booking=Booking::where('room_id',$room->id)->get();
            $booking=DB::table('rooms')
            ->leftjoin('bookings','bookings.room_id','=','rooms.id')
            ->where([['bookings.check_in_date', '<', $request->c_in_date],['bookings.check_out_date', '<', $request->c_out_date]])
            ->orwhere([['bookings.check_in_date', '>', $request->c_in_date],['bookings.check_out_date', '>', $request->c_out_date]])
            ->get();

            if($booking){
               return redirect()->route('room.book_now',$id)->with('warning','Room already Booked');
            }
```

Now problem is that, if someone to book a room in 17-10-2020-----20-10-2020 on this date, it will be booked. But logically it can't. If the same room is already booked in this during, it will show the message: "room is booked", otherwise do the next closure.

How can I solve this problem?
What is the actual SQL query for that in laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a join query since you already have room_id which is also stored in bookings table.

I assume check-in and check out are stored as date in your database, so we need to convert in into date first before doing any comparison.

We also don't need to check the check out date of the room. if the room is check-in between the user given date range, that means room is not available. So just check the check-in date.

```
$check_in = date($request->c_in_date);
$check_out = date($request->c_out_date);
$booking=DB::table('bookings')
            ->where('room_id',$id)
            ->whereBetween('check_in_date',[$check_in,$check_out])
            ->get();
```